# A white line sticks on the top of on my MacBook Pro 15 inch 2016's screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, screen

Recently I've bought I new MacBook Pro 15 inch and after a while I noticed that a **thin white line** appears on the top of my MacBook Pro's screen as it's shown in the pictures below:

[image: Image number 1]

[image: Image number 2]

> Please note that I have installed Windows 10 on my device too (using
> bootcamp) and this issue does not show up in windows at all.

My macOS version is **Sierra**.

How can I fix this issue? Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: I have had similar issues (such as menu bar content not aligning) in Sierra which were all fixed after a reboot. Have you been able to reboot yet?

Comment: @ProGrammer Yeah when I reboot my mac it disappears but after a while it shows up again. Even sometimes rebooting is affectless.

Comment: Odd, just thought I'd pass that encounter along to see if it helped in any way. Since the problem occurs intermittently, I think we can agree it's a software issue. Are you able to upgrade to the latest macOS High Sierra (10.13.2)? It will most likely have been patched.

Comment: I upgraded to high sierra but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be Kaspersky try to unload it

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] to add a few more details on how exactly one should try unloading Kaspersky (and undoing the unload).

Comment: Yeah it was true,My Kaspersky account was finished and I hadn't purchased a new one. when I quit it that white line disappears. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem vaguely like that that turned out to be in one case an icon and in another case an oddly placed window.

Try this. Open a Finder window and look at the contents of your desktop in list view. Compare that to the icons that show up on the desktop if there is seemingly one or more icons in list view of the Desktop folder that may be the cluprit. Delete it or move it elsewhere.

Close or hide all windows on the desktop. Tap <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>. See if the line disappears.

Quit out of all open applications, ALL of them. Tap <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is there anything in the list besides Finder?

Change your desktop background to an Apple supplied picture, and try a solid color (one light, one dark) see if the line vanishes. It might be a part of your desktop background, though that is less likely if it shows up in other apps.

Boot the Mac in safe mode. If the line disappears it is something that you installed that runs automatically and puts that line there. Start removing startup items.

Comment: I tried them all, but I still have this problem. I even upgraded to high sierra but nothing changed.

Comment: I don't believe that it's a hardware issue cause it never shows up in Windows 10 that has been installed using Boot Camp.